# Does flattening affect pricing in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery supports repeating, array columns. These can be expanded ("flattened") by using the [FLATTEN](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#flatten) function. Since pricing in BigQuery is bound to the size of the dataset (the used column to be more precise), does flattening make my queries more expensive since it affects the size of the dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, flattening doesn't affect the cost, since it doesn't actually expand the amount of data needed to be read by BigQuery.